# How to get current day's high, low, open price for a script in pine script?

Tags: pine-script

Hi I'm pretty new to pine script. So sorry if I'm missing something very obvious.
I'm trying to plot current day's open, high , low and close on a given script . For that I'm using below code.

```
strategy("Intraday Test Strategy", overlay=true)


dh = security(syminfo.tickerid,"D",high)
do = security(syminfo.tickerid,"D",open)
dl = security(syminfo.tickerid,"D",low)

plot(dh, title="High",color=color.red,linewidth=2,trackprice=true)
plot(do, title="Open",color=color.yellow,linewidth=2,trackprice=true)
plot(dl, title="Low",color=color.green,linewidth=2,trackprice=true)
```

When I execute this all  I see is previous day's high, Open, Low prices and not current day's high, Open, Low prices. Its clear I'm missing something very basic. I would appreciate very much if u clarify what I'm missing here.

[image: SPY]

As we can from above pic the previous day's open, low and high prices are plotted where as i need current day's values.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just like in the real world, Pine cannot look into the future.
So, when you're at the start of a day, there's no way to know what the `high` and `low` will be.

However, Pine does allow to look ahead on historical bars, because on those bars, the `high` and `low` points for that day are known.

```
//@version=4
study("Test", "Test", true)

[do,dh,dl] = security(syminfo.ticker, "D", [open,high,low], lookahead=barmerge.lookahead_on)

plot(dh, title="High", color=color.red,    linewidth=2, trackprice=true)
plot(do, title="Open", color=color.yellow, linewidth=2, trackprice=true)
plot(dl, title="Low",  color=color.green,  linewidth=2, trackprice=true)
```

You must be careful though, because the `lookahead` values will only be correct for days in the past.

Comment: Thank you man.This is what i was looking for, coz I was bit confused to see previous day's open , low and high plotted on today's candles. This flag makes things to look clear in chart for current day . I really appreciate ur time and effort.

Comment: this answer plots something from an open but its not the daily open. Mine is 20 bucks of of the chart im watching on.

Comment: Pine likes to create problems where isn't any. There is no need to look into the future when we are looking at the __current__ day (I mean there is no different behavior than we already have, 1. historical bars, 2. real time bar). Pine should exactly know what the **High** and **Low** are. They can change at every tick for the current day like on a real-time bar just Open is fixed as it is in the past and can never change. Scripts can already work on a realtime bar so why there is mystery for a script on a lower time frame working with "D" and having that "D" time act as a real time bar?

Answer (score 0):

With this one you can see how the HOD and LOD move with the plot.

```
indicator("OHL OD Chart", "OHL", overlay = true)


FirstCandel = if session.isfirstbar
    0
else
    ta.barssince(session.isfirstbar)
OPEN = if session.isfirstbar
    //line.delete(NextOpenLine[3])
    open
HOD = if FirstCandel < 1
    high
else
    OpenHOD_CANDEL = ta.barssince(session.isfirstbar)
    ta.highest(high, FirstCandel)
LOD = if FirstCandel < 1
    low
else
    OpenHOD_CANDEL = ta.barssince(session.isfirstbar)
    ta.lowest(low, FirstCandel)
COD = if session.islastbar
    close
plot(HOD, "HOD", color.red, linewidth = 1, trackprice = true)
plot(LOD, "LOD", color.green, linewidth = 1, trackprice = true)
plot(OPEN, "OPEN", color.yellow, linewidth = 1, trackprice = true)
plot(COD,"CLOSE", color.blue, linewidth = 1, trackprice = true)
```